# Update and Delete using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, database

This is my first ever database with AJAX. I'm really lost now, I don't know what to do next.

I already done in the part I can insert data in database and viewing it in website as well. Updating the data is not done yet and it can only fetch data from database in the fill up form but it won't able to insert it in database. Deleting data by row is also my problem.

```html
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 ?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
 <head>  
  <title>Database</title>  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

 

 </head>  
 <body>  
    <h3 class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" align="center">Registration Database</h3>  
  

  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <div align="right">

     <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" value="Add User" class="btn btn-primary">
     </input>


    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="employee_table">
      <br />
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <tr class = thead-dark>
       <th width="40%">First Name</th>
       <th width="40%">Last Name</th>
       <th width="5%">View</th>
       <th width="5%">Update</th>
       <th width="5">Delete</th>

       
      </tr>
      <?php
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      ?>
      
      <tr id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" >
       <td data-target="firstname"><?php echo $row["firstname"]; ?></td>
       <td data-target="lastname"><?php echo $row["lastname"]; ?></td>
       <td>
        <input type="button" name="view" value="View" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm view_data" >
       </td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" name="update" value="Update" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm update_data" >
          <td>
            <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_data" >
           
          </td>
      
      <?php
      }
      ?>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
  <br />
  
  <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary mx-auto d-block">Back to Top</button>

  

 </body>  
</html>  

<div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add User to Database</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <form method="post" id="insert_form" >
     <label>Full Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="middlename" id="middlename" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Middle Name" />
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
     <br />
     <label>Address</label>
     <input type="text" name="street" id="street" class="form-control" placeholder="Street">
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="barangay" id="barangay" class="form-control" placeholder="Barangay">
     <br />
     <select name="city" class="form-control">
        <option value="Caloocan">Caloocan</option>
        <option value="Las Piñas‎">Las Piñas‎</option>
        <option value="Makati">Makati</option>
        <option value="Malabon">Malabon</option>
        <option value="Mandaluyong">Mandaluyong</option>
        <option value="Manila">Manila</option>
        <option value="Marikina">Marikina</option>
        <option value="Muntinlupa">Muntinlupa</option>
        <option value="Navotas">Navotas</option>
        <option value="Parañaque">Parañaque</option>
        <option value="Pasay">Pasay</option>
        <option value="Pasig">Pasig</option>
        <option value="Quezon City">Quezon City</option>
        <option value="San Juan">San Juan</option>
        <option value="Taguig">Taguig</option>
        <option value="Valenzuela">Valenzuela</option>
     </select>
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code">
     <br />
     <label>Birth Date</label><br />
        <input type="date" value="date" id="date" name="birthday" class="form-control" locked onblur="getAge();" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"  />
        <br />
     <label for="age">Age</label><br /> 
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Age" readonly>
        <br />
     <label>Gender</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" > Male<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br />
     <br />
     <label>Contact Number</label>
      <br />
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">+63</span>
      <input type="text" name="contactnumber" id="contactnumber" class="form-control" placeholder="919 123 4567 - sample pattern" maxlength="12">
      <br />  
    </div>
     <label>Parents Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="fathername" id="fathername" class="form-control" placeholder="Father Name" />
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="mothername" id="mothername" class="form-control" placeholder="Mother Name" />
     <br />
     <input type="submit" name="insertbutton" id="insertbutton" value="SAVE" class="btn btn-success" />
    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div id="update_data_Modal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    
    <h4 class="modal-title">Update User to Database</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body " id="update_detail">
    

   </div>

   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
   
    <h4 class="modal-title">User Details</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">
    
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#insert_form',).on("submit", function(event){  
  event.preventDefault();  
  if($('#firstname').val() == "")  
  {  
   alert("First Name is required");  
  }  
  else if($('#middlename').val() == '')  
  {  
   alert("Middle Name is required");  
  }  
  else if($('#lastname').val() == '')
  {  
   alert("Last Name is required");  
  }
  else if($('#street').val() == '')
  {
    alert("Street is required");
  }

  else if($('#barangay').val() == '')
  {
    alert("Barangay is required");
  }
  
  else if($('#city').val() == '')
  {
    alert("City is required");
  }

   else if($('#zipcode').val() == '')
  {
    alert("Zip Code is required");
  }

 else if($('#birthday').val() == '')
  {
    alert("Birthday is required");
  }

   else if($('#age').val() == '')
  {
    alert("Age is required");
  }

   else if($('#gender').val() == '')
  {
    alert("Gender is required");
  }

 else if($('#contactnumber').val() == '')
  {
    alert("Contact Number is required");
  }

   else if($('#fathername').val() == '')
  {
    alert("Father Name is required");
  }

   else if($('#mothername').val() == '')
  {
    alert("Mother Name is required");
  }




  else  
  {  
   $.ajax({  
    url:"insert.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
    beforeSend:function(){  
     $('#insertbutton').val("Inserting");  
    },  
    success:function(data){  
     $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
     $('#employee_table').html(data);  
    }  
   });  
  }  
 });



 $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){
  //$('#dataModal').modal();
  var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
   url:"select.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{employee_id:employee_id},
   success:function(data){
    $('#employee_detail').html(data);
    $('#dataModal').modal('show');
   }
  });
 });
});


 $(document).on('click', '.update_data', function(){
  //$('#dataModal').modal();
  var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
   url:"update.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{employee_id:employee_id},
   success:function(data){
    $('#update_detail').html(data);
    $('#update_data_Modal').modal('show');
   }
  });
 });






function getAge(){
 var birthday = document.getElementById('date').value;
 birthday = new Date(birthday);
 var today = new Date();
 var age = Math.floor((today-birthday) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
 document.getElementById('age').value=age;
          }



var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}






 </script>
```

```html
INSERT

<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $output = '';
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["firstname"]);  
    $middlename = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["middlename"]);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["lastname"]);
    $street = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["street"]);
    $barangay = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["barangay"]);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["city"]);
    $zipcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["zipcode"]);
    $birthday = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["birthday"]);
    $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["age"]);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["gender"]);
    $contactnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["contactnumber"]);
    $fathername = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["fathername"]);
    $mothername = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["mothername"]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_users(firstname, middlename, lastname, street, barangay, city, zipcode, birthday, age, gender, contactnumber, fathername, mothername) VALUES ('$firstname', '$middlename', '$lastname', '$street', '$barangay', '$city', '$zipcode','$birthday','$age','$gender','$contactnumber','$fathername','$mothername')";

    if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
    {
     $output .= '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Success!</strong> User is added in the database.
                </div>';
     $select_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY id DESC";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select_query);
     $output .= '
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">  
                    <tr class = thead-dark>  
                       <th width="40%">First Name</th>
                       <th width="40%">Last Name</th>
                       <th width="5%">View</th>
                       <th width="5%">Update</th>
                       <th width="5">Delete</th>
                    </tr>

     ';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $output .= '
                    
                    <tr>  
                         <td>' . $row["firstname"] . '</td>
                         <td>' . $row["lastname"] . '</td>   
                         <td><input type="button" name="view" value="View" id="' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm view_data" /></td>
                         <td><input type="button" name="update" value="Update" id="' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-success btn-sm update_data" ></td>
                         <td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" id="' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_data" ></td>  
                    </tr>
      ';
     }
     $output .= '</table>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

```html
UPDATE

<?php  

if(isset($_POST["employee_id"]))
{
 $output = '';
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE id = '".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $output .= '
        <form method="post" id="edit_form" >
            <label>Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" value='.$row["firstname"].' class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" readonly /> <br />
            <input type="text" value='.$row["middlename"].' class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name" readonly /> <br />
            <input type="text" value='.$row["lastname"].' class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" readonly /> <br />

            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="street" value='.$row["street"].' class="form-control" placeholder="Street" /> <br />
            <input type="text" id="barangay" value='.$row["barangay"].' class="form-control" placeholder="Barangay" /> <br />
        
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Caloocan">Caloocan</option>
                    <option value="Las Piñas‎">Las Piñas‎</option>
                    <option value="Makati">Makati</option>
                    <option value="Malabon">Malabon</option>
                    <option value="Mandaluyong">Mandaluyong</option>
                    <option value="Manila">Manila</option>
                    <option value="Marikina">Marikina</option>
                    <option value="Muntinlupa">Muntinlupa</option>
                    <option value="Navotas">Navotas</option>
                    <option value="Parañaque">Parañaque</option>
                    <option value="Pasay">Pasay</option>
                    <option value="Pasig">Pasig</option>
                    <option value="Quezon City">Quezon City</option>
                    <option value="San Juan">San Juan</option>
                    <option value="Taguig">Taguig</option>
                    <option value="Valenzuela">Valenzuela</option>
            </select><br />
            <input type="text" value='.$row["zipcode"].' class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" /> <br />

            <label>Birth Date</label>
            <br />
            <input type="date" value='.$row["birthday"].' class="form-control" readonly />
            <br />

            <label>Age</label>
            <input type="text" value='.$row["age"].' class="form-control" readonly />

            <label>Gender</label>

            <input type="text" value='.$row["gender"].' class="form-control" readonly />
            <br />

            <label>Contact Number</label>
            <input type="text" value='.$row["contactnumber"].' class="form-control" placeholder="919 123 4567 - sample pattern" maxlength="12"><br />

            <label>Parents Name</label>
            <input type="text" value='.$row["fathername"].' class="form-control" readonly />
            <br />
            <input type="text" value='.$row["mothername"].' class="form-control" readonly />
            <br />
            <button type="submit" id="update" class="btn btn-success">UPDATE1</button>


        </form>
     ';


    }
   
    echo $output;
}





?>
```

Comment: Your HTML seems invalid. Can you please format your code?

Comment: See this tutorial https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php scroll down to **Creating the Update Page** all method are working, they have 3 methods procedural (which is your solution) I tried earlier object and pdo. and change your html tag with this `<!doctype html><html lang="en">`

Comment: I forgot to put my database thats why it shows an error

Comment: Is there anything here to do with ajax? looks like php to me.

Comment: Its in far below of html code. Im really sorry, im really new to this